# distributed erlang. Client cant see registered pid from server

Tags: erlang

I newbie in erlang. I cant understand why my program dont work. Help me please.

```
server() ->
        io:format("server ~n"),
        register( doServer, Pid = spawn(node(), ?MODULE, doServer,[[]])),
        io:format("server ~p ~n", [registered()]).

client() ->
        io:format("client ~p ~n", [registered()]),
        spawn_clients(1).
```

Server do register(atom, PID)

```
register( doServer, Pid = spawn(node(), ?MODULE, doServer,[[]])),

erlc smplMessenger.erl ;  echo " ****** RUN *******"; \
erl -noshell -sname p1 +v setcookie k1 -s smplMessenger server 

 ****** RUN *******
server 
server [code_server,erl_prim_loader,application_controller,kernel_safe_sup,
        standard_error_sup,inet_db,init,erts_code_purger,user,***doServer***,
        error_logger,rex,kernel_sup,erl_signal_server,global_name_server,
        standard_error,global_group,file_server_2] 
Start server
```

In print "registered()." I can see alias "**doServer**"

But client cant see alias "**doServer**" and its PID

```
erl -noshell setcookie k1 -sname p2  -s smplMessenger client 
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.3] [source] [smp:2:2] [ds:2:2:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

client [code_server,erl_prim_loader,application_controller,erl_epmd,auth,
        standard_error_sup,net_kernel,inet_db,init,erts_code_purger,user,
        error_logger,rex,net_sup,kernel_sup,user_drv,kernel_safe_sup,
        erl_signal_server,global_name_server,standard_error,global_group,
        file_server_2] 
[Client <0.5.0>] node 1 spawned 
All client spawned
[Client <0.67.0> 1] Start client with serv pid undefined. Im alive 

=ERROR REPORT==== 31-May-2018::21:52:07 ===
Error in process <0.67.0> on node p2@station with exit value:
{badarg,[{smplMessenger,doClient,1,[{file,"smplMessenger.erl"},{line,121}]}]}
```

line 121 is

```
118: doClient(Name) ->
119:        io:format("[Client ~p ~p] Start client with serv pid ~p. Im alive ~n",
120:                        [self(), Name, whereis(doServer)]),
121:        doServer ! {isAlive, self(), Name},
121:
122:        clientRecv(Name),
123:
124:        io:format("[Client ~p ~p] FINISH CLIENT ~n",
125:                        [self(), Name]).
```

I run two nodes from one computer (Cooke in two nodes is equal).

epmd see client and server processes.

Node 1 and node 2 can ping both of.

```
netstat -tuwpln
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address Foreign Address State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4369            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1408/epmd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:36499           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3008/beam.smp
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:33865           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3047/beam.smp
tcp6       0      0 :::4369                 :::*                    LISTEN      1408/epmd
tcp7       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

Where I wrong ? Help me.

I change register to global but client process cant see server (doServer) anything.

```
server() ->
        io:format("server ~n"),
        global:register_name( doServer, spawn(node(), ?MODULE, doServer,[[]])),
        io:format("server ~p ~n", [global:registered_names()]).


client() ->
        io:format("[Client ~p ] ~p ~n",
                        [self(), global:whereis_name(doServer)]),
        io:format("client ~p ~n", [global:registered_names()]).

erlc smplMessenger.erl ;  echo " ****** RUN *******"; erl -noshell -sname p1 -v -setcookie k1 -s smplMessenger server
 ****** RUN *******
server 
Start server 
server [doServer]

erlc smplMessenger.erl ;  echo " ****** RUN *******"; erl -noshell -sname p2 -v -setcookie k1 -s smplMessenger client

****** RUN *******
[Client <0.5.0> ] undefined 
client []
```

Answer (score 1):

function `registered()` ( It's actually `erlang:registered/0` MFA. MFA stands for Module, Function, Arity.`/0` is arity and means it accepts 0 arguments) shows registered processes and ports which are registered using `erlang:register/2`. `erlang:register/2` registers a name for a process or port **locally** then works per node and only for that node. This means node `p1` has its own registered processes and does not know about registered processes of other nodes. Also Node `p2` does not know about registered process of other nodes.
I recommed to use [**`global`**](http://erlang.org/doc/man/global.html) module to register a name for a process in a system consisting many Erlang nodes.
For above example you need functions `global:register_name/2` and `global:registered_names/0`. Also you should connect second started node to first node before these operations.

Comment: Thanks vary match.

Comment: that do you mean "Also you shoul connect second started node to first node before these operations." ?  I change register to global:register_name, registered to global:registered_names and whereis to global:whereis_name(doServer) but client process cant see server (doServer) anything.

Comment: You have to connect nodes together. use net_adm:ping/1 for example. I recommend to read the global code https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/master/lib/kernel/src/global.erl